# Android , SQLite.... the primary key is inserted as null

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

I'm a beginner with android, and trying to create a database. with one table and three functions add , delete, update and retrieve.

When I insert an item to the data base the primary key will be given a number that is incremented each time .. but it is inserted to the database as null !

Therefore I couldn't update and delete records because I need the id. 
and for the retrieve the output works fine except for the id it is null.

Here is the schema

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "alarmapp"; 
private static final String CREATE_alarm= "CREATE TABLE alarm" +
        " (Aid integer  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "message varchar(100)," +
        "date varchar(100));";
```

and here is the insert code:

```
// columns 
private static final String AI = "Aid";
private static final String Message= "message";
private static final String Date = "date";

// tables
private static final String TABLE_NAME= "alarm";

private Context context;
private DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public long add( String message, String date) {
    ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

    values.put(Message,message);
    values.put(Date, date);

    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,values);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following link:
http://www.androidph.com/2012/01/android-sqlite-primary-key-auto.html

Comment: @proG your `integer  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT` is weird (sqlite3 detects it as syntax error here), and it's not quite like the "correct" example in the link posted by @user1122549.

Comment: I had `INT PRIMARY KEY` and it didn't work until I changed it to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. Thanks.

Comment: @conca You just became my hero! Thanks a lot for pointing that out. After playing around with copying the DB it seems like SQLite changed the `INTEGER` col to `INT`...

Comment: Downvoted because it's a link-only answer, I'll revert it upon improving (but thanks for link :) )

Comment: @conca You just solved a bug which was driving me crazy for last 1 hour. Thanks a lot!